# Create dictionary from lists with condition

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement

Here's what I have:

```
ports = [ 1111, 2222, 3333 ]
keys = ['port', 'target_port', 'name']
ports = [dict.fromkeys(keys, port) for port in ports]
```

this produces:

```
[
    {
        "port": 1111,
        "target_port": 1111,
        "name": 1111
    }
    xxx
]
```

the problem is value of "name" needs to be a string. how can I add a condition to the list comprehension? All the other values have to remain integers

EDIT: my workaround for now:

```
for port_dict in ports:
    port_dict['name'] = str(port_dict['port'])
```

Ended up using the reverse of the accepted answer so I can potentially add keys to the end of the list:

```
keys = ['name', 'port', 'target_port']
ports = [{**dict.fromkeys(keys[1:], port), "name": str(port)}
         for port in ports]
```

Comment: `ports["name"] = str(ports["name"])`

Comment: seeing how this is -3, can anybody explain what is wrong with this legitimate question?

Comment: I'm guessing that the down-votes are because you didn't attempt a solution.  Changing a datum from integer to string is a simple operation.  Your solution may not have been pretty, but it's often advantageous to ask "how do I do this in a single statement?", rather than "how do I do this at all?"

Comment: i did, i even showed my current solution, i'm just looking for something cleaner. nobody reads the question? :)

Comment: All that minuses are rather discouraging for people that ask valid questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
ports = [ 1111, 2222, 3333 ]
keys = ['port', 'target_port', 'name']

result = [{ **dict.fromkeys(keys[:2], port), "name" : str(port) } for port in ports]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'target_port': 1111, 'name': '1111', 'port': 1111}, {'target_port': 2222, 'name': '2222', 'port': 2222}, {'target_port': 3333, 'name': '3333', 'port': 3333}]
```

Comment: sorry, this is a bit too clever for me, what does **dict.fromkeys() do?

Comment: This solution is great, but if `'name'` moves position or the `keys` are longer, it would be more complex to scale.  `**dict.fromkeys()` basically unpack the dictionary.

Comment: @4c74356b41 As Idlehands said it unpacks the dictionary it a way it can be combined inside a dictionary literal.

Comment: can i reverse it: `keys[1:], str(port)` and just make sure name is always first?

Comment: Then do `{"name" : str(port), **dict.fromkeys(keys[:2], port)}` instead.  Note insertion order only matters if your Python version is 3.6+

Comment: @4c74356b41 Just remember the order is only guaranteed in Python 3.6+

Comment: @Daniel Mesejo If you're going to go down this route, why not simply do: `[{"port": port, "target_port": port, "name": str(port)} for port in ports]`?

Comment: @ekhumoro that could be an option too.

Comment: @ekhumoro because if the keys change, that code is no longer valid and needs to be rewritten to account for the new keys.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy If the key(s) or its (their) position changes, this code will need to be rewritten too.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy It makes no difference whether the keys are specified direcly in the list-comp or in a separate list, just so long as they are only specified *once*. In fact, my solution avoids specifiying the `"name"` key twice, which is a further improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing `dict.fromkeys()`, you could simply write it out, nesting a dict comprehension inside the list comprehension:

```
ports = [ {key: (str(port) if key == "name" else port) for key in keys}
          for port in ports]
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Mesejo gave a nice solution, but for a little bit scale-ability you can define your own function to use in a dictionary comprehension:

```
def force_str(val, key, str_keys):
    if key in str_keys:
        return str(val)
    else:
        return val

result = [{k: force_str(p, k, ['name']) for k in keys} for p in ports]

# [{'port': 1111, 'target_port': 1111, 'name': '1111'}, 
#  {'port': 2222, 'target_port': 2222, 'name': '2222'}, 
#  {'port': 3333, 'target_port': 3333, 'name': '3333'}]
```

This allow you to pass an arbitrary amount of `str_keys` into your function, and the `key` can be in any position.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using below

```
[{key: str(port) if key=="name" else port for key in keys} for port in ports]
```

Comment: This solution has [already been given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54579982/984421).